# Match cells of different values in different columns

Tags: excel, compare

I am trying to figure out the following:
I have two columns ranging from A2:A316 and B2:316.
In column A I have the values A/A, A/T, or T/T.  In column B
I have the values G/G, C/G, or C/C.

Is there a formula that I can write in a new column, that can find combinations
such as A/A  in one column and C/C in another (in the same row). So that excel returns some value (e.g. 1) when it finds A/A in A and C/C in column B.
and 0 if its A/A or T/T in column A and A/T in column B. I want to find how many rows are A/A  and   T/T respectively (in column A) and G/G and C/C in col B.

Best regards,
Granit

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy to do this.

In Column C put something like...

In C1...

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="A/A",B1="C/C"), AND(A1="A/A",B1="T/T"), AND(A1="A/A",B1="A/T")), 1, 0)
```

Just add more to the OR statement for the extra pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A75,"A/A",B1:B75,"C/C")
```

this should do the trick for you it will count you all A/A C/C combinations in given range

Comment: Supernice. Thanx. This was what I was looking for!